# Sum of factorials in Java

Tags: java

I made a program to sum factorials in java like `4! + 3! + 2! + 1! = 33`, but it doesn't work. Could anyone help explain why?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class fac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = 0, fact, i, j;
        fact = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ENTER NO"));
        for (i = fact; i > 1; i--) {
            for (j = fact - 1; j > 0; j--)
                fact = fact * j;
            sum = sum + fact;
        }
        sum = sum + 1;
        System.out.print("SUM OF FACTORIAL = "+sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote it, you explain it.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean that it doesn't compile, it doesn't run, it throws an exception, it gives the wrong result? any clues? just a hint?

Comment: Step through it and see what gets added to `sum`.

Comment: **Please** debug your code before coming here to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where methods might come in handy. First an outer loop because you're counting down (from `4`, in this example).

```
static final int NR = 4; //for example

static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = NR; i > 0; i--)
        total += calculateFactorial(i); //i += j; is the same as i = i + j;
    System.out.println("Answer: " + total);
}
```

Now it looks way easier, right? The code suddenly became readable. Now for `calculateFactorial(int nr)` all we have to do is calculate `4 * 3 * 2 * 1` (for the factorial of `4`, that is):

```
public static int calculateFactorial(int nr) {
    int factorialTotal = 1;
    for (int i = nr; i > 0; i--)
        factorialTotal *= i; //i *= j; is the same as i = i * j;
    return factorialTotal;
}
```

Methods just made code easy to read and write. I'd suggest you read a book like [Clean Code](http://books.google.com/books/about/Clean_Code.html?id=_i6bDeoCQzsC&redir_esc=y)

Answer (score 1):

You are repeatingly calculating factorial of fact in the outer loop. The start value of the inner loop is wrong.

But you should have found this error by yourself using a debugger.